# How to calculate RDS snapshot pricing for one month retained?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-billing

I am confused by how to calculate pricing for AWS MYSQL RDS backups. AWS mentioned that

> there is no additional charge for backup storage, up to 100% of total database storage for a region

But i couldn't get this point. How to calculate for below case?

- Cloud - AWS
- Database - RDS
- Region - Anyone
- Instance type - db.t2.medium
- Storage size - 20 GB
- RDS backups - Two additional backups per day (Backups retained for one month) and monthly full backup (Backups retained for one year)

How we can calculate above things? I need to give exact pricing for RDS backups.

Comment: Dear all, Is my question was  wrong? No one replied.